# Spring boot deserialization for two models

Tags: spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I want to deserialize json into two models which are not related, after some research about custom deserialization in JACKSON I cannot see how I can do it?

I know I can solve the issue by creating a wrapper model for the two models but isnt there a way to deserialize on the fly without JACKSON?

Answer (score 0):

I can use ObjectMapper twice for the same json input. you may need some annotation like

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

and/or

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```

on the producer side can help too. 
if you give us your two models ?

Comment: if I am going to create 2 object mappers, I think creating a serializable mapper would be a cleaner solution, what I am looking for is deserializing on the fly